# Fill Material Design Data Table in AngularJS with Firebase data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, datatable, angularjs-material

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table#usage) module of AngularJS to create a table with information stored in Firebase. The problem is that I can not get the table populated with the data obtained in Firebase. At the moment of loading the page, the [progress bar](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table#table-progress) appears, but when it finishes receiving the Firebase information and the progress bar ends, nothing is shown in the table. It remains as you can see in the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlWeW.png), it also shows how the information is loaded, since it is being printed by the console.

The table has the following structure:

```
 <md-table-container>
  <table md-table md-row-select="options.rowSelection" multiple="{{options.multiSelect}}" ng-model="selected" md-progress="promise">
    <thead md-head md-order="query.order" md-on-reorder="cargarPacientes">
    <tr md-row>
      <th md-column md-order-by="nombre"><span>Nombre</span></th>
      <th md-column md-order-by="type"><span>Fecha Nacimiento</span></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody md-body>
    <tr md-row md-select="paciente" md-on-select="logItem" md-auto-select="options.autoSelect" ng-repeat="paciente in pacientes.data | filter: filter.search | orderBy: query.order | limitTo: query.limit : (query.page -1) * query.limit">
      <td md-cell>{{paciente.nombre + " " + paciente.apellido}}</td>
      <td md-cell>{{paciente}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</md-table-container>
```

And the code with which I access Firebase to obtain the information is:

```
$scope.pacientes = cargarPacientes();

  function cargarPacientes() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.promise = deferred.promise;
    let pacientesMostrar = {};
    let pacientes = [];
    let database = firebase.database();
    let pacientesRef = database.ref('pacientes');
    $timeout (function () {
      pacientesRef.once('value').then(function(paciente) {
        paciente.forEach(function (pacienteHijo) {
          let childData = pacienteHijo.val();
          childData['key'] = pacienteHijo.key;
          pacientes.push(childData);
        });
        pacientesMostrar['count'] = pacientes.length;
        pacientesMostrar['data'] = pacientes;
        console.log(pacientesMostrar);
        deferred.resolve();
        return pacientes;
      }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        deferred.reject();
      });

    }, 2000);
  };
```

I am not sure that I am using the promises correctly, nor that I am correctly assigning the information obtained from Firebase to the variable `$ scope.patients`.
You can see the expected behavior in the following [demo](http://danielnagy.me/md-data-table/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  cargarPacientes().then(function(data){
      $scope.pacientes = data;
  })

  function cargarPacientes() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    let pacientesMostrar = {};
    let pacientes = [];
    let database = firebase.database();
    let pacientesRef = database.ref('pacientes');
    $timeout (function () {
      pacientesRef.once('value').then(function(paciente) {
        paciente.forEach(function (pacienteHijo) {
          let childData = pacienteHijo.val();
          childData['key'] = pacienteHijo.key;
          pacientes.push(childData);
        });
        pacientesMostrar['count'] = pacientes.length;
        pacientesMostrar['data'] = pacientes;
        console.log(pacientesMostrar);
        deferred.resolve(pacientesMostrar);

      }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        deferred.reject(error);
      });

    }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise
  };
```

The way you are implementing `promise` is wrong.

The promise is something which doesnt happen right away, rather it is asynchronous (may take 1 sec to `n` secs). So, we return `deferred.promise` and then assign the resolved values (which will come after `n` secs) to `deferred.resolve(data)` and similarly for `rejection`.

And then `$scope.pacientes` is put under `then()` function